# QWT for PyQGIS with QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, graph

I developped a plugin on QGIS 2.18, and used qwt5 to implement an elevation graph, which works quite well.

Now that a want to migrate my plugin to QGIS3, and knowing that qwt5 is linked to PyQt4, I'm not able to find which module to use in my Python code, or even to know if qwt (6 or else) is still available in QGIS3. In OSGEO4W setup installation, it still seems to be available, but I don't know how to call it in my code.

Answer :
I finally found the python3-qwt packages in OSGeo4W Setup. Cannot say if it's new or if I missed it before.

Comment: Have you seen this [Qwt5 using Qt5](https://github.com/gbm19/qwt5-qt5)?

Comment: Qwt (C++) is available but the Python part is not available by default to my knowledge in build (See in QGIS "Help" > "About" to confirm there is a Qwt part). IMHO, to be sure for the Python side, you should open an issue at official tracker https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues

Comment: @Taras I meant embedded in QGIS. For now I don't want to add an external dependancy to my QGIS plugin, which will be a lot of complication for users.

Comment: @ThomasG77 My QGIS3 seems to contain Qwt6. Thanks for the idea of the issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution to use qwt from Python with QGIS 3 ?